# JS date calculation with UTC stored on server?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm passing back a UTC date from the server, and I need some JS to find the difference in seconds between "now" and the date passed back from the server.

I'm currently trying moment, with something like

```
var lastUpdatedDate = moment(utcStringFromServer);
var currentDate = moment();
var diff = currentDate - lastUpdatedDate;
```

problem is, this gives a very invalid answer, because UTC is coming down from the server, and creating a new `moment()` makes it local. How can I do a calculation with respect to full UTC so it's agnostic of any local timing?

Comment: Have you tried [`.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you aren't quite understanding is that Dates are stored as the number of milliseconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1970 in UTC time. When determining the date/time in the local timezone of the browser, it first works out what the date/time would be in UTC time, then adds/subtracts the local timezone offset.

When you turn a Date back into a number, using `+dateVar` or `dateVar.valueOf()` or similar, it is back to the number of milliseconds since 01/01/1970T00:00:00Z.

The nice part about this is that whenever you serialise dates in UTC (either as a number, or as ISO String format), when it gets automatically converted to local time by Javascript's `Date` object, it is exactly the same point in time as the original value, just represented in local time.

So in your case, when you convert a local date to a number, you get a value of milliseconds in UTC that you are subtracting a value in milliseconds in UTC from. The result will be the number of milliseconds that has passed between the time from the server and the time the `new Date()` call is made.

Where it gets tricky is when you want a timestamp from the server to *not* be translated to local time, because you want to show the hours and minutes the same regardless of timezone. But that is not what you need in this case.

Comment: You are correct - I had a fundamental misunderstanding about how dates in JS were represented. This solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this way hope it may help:

```
    var lastUpdatedDate = moment(utcStringFromServer);
    var date = Date.UTC();
    var currentDate = moment(date);
    var diff = currentDate - lastUpdatedDate;
```

Comment: [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) will return `NaN` if you don't pass any parameters to it.

Comment: yeah @AstroCB I just checked

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `utcStringFromServer` is something like this:

```
Fri, 19 Aug 2016 04:27:27 GMT
```

If that's the case, you don't really need Moment.js at all. If you pass that string to [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), it'll return the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970. You can then use the [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method to get the same info about right now (converted to UTC) and parse it the same way to get milliseconds since 1970. Then, you can subtract the former from the latter and divide it by 1000 to convert back to seconds.

All in all, it would look something like this:

```js
var lastUpdatedDate = Date.parse(utcStringFromServer);
var currentDate = Date.parse((new Date()).toISOString())
var diff = (currentDate - lastUpdatedDate) / 1000.0; // Convert from milliseconds
```